# always showing access denied page using spring security in struts2

Tags: html, jsp, spring-security, struts2, struts-action

I am developing a simple `struts2` login page using spring security.The problem is that whenever I login, it always show my custom access denied page no matter the user is valid or not. I don't understand the error, as no error is showing except a warning:

> org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer.warn No configuration found for the specified action: 'j_spring_security_check' in namespace: '/'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.

my web.xml

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>  
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

my applicationContext-security.xml

```xml
 <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/direct.action" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin.action" access="hasRole('ROLE_Admin')" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/jsp/deniedAccess.jsp" />

    <form-login login-page="/jsp/login.jsp" default-target-url="/admin.action" 
                authentication-failure-url="/validateUser.action?error" 
                username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.action?logout" />       
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_User" />
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="direct" class="action.LogAction" method="reDirect">
        <result name="success">/jsp/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="admin" class="action.LogAction" method="directAdmin">
        <result name="success">/admin/adminHome.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="validateUser" class="action.LogAction" method="errorDirect">
        <result name="success">/jsp/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="logout" class="action.LogAction" method="directLogout">
        <result name="success">/jsp/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

index.jsp

```xml
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
</head>
<body>
    Redirecting...
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=direct.action">
</body>
```

I don't know what is the error.Any help will be appreciated

login.jsp

```xml
 <s:form action="j_spring_security_check" namespace="/" method="post">
            <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"/>
            <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
            <s:submit align="center" value="Login"/> 
        </s:form>
```

Comment: Use `<form>` tag instead of S2 `<s:form>` tag in your login page.

Comment: `j_spring_security_check` is not an action and you should exclude it from mapping.

Comment: @Roman sir,as u suggested i removed j_spring_security_check from mapping,but still no change

Comment: Show your `login.jsp`.

Comment: @ Aleksandr sir,i updated the question with my login page and thanks for ur interest

Comment: And now read my first comment and follow it.

Comment: Your admin user will never be able to login as you are assigning it ROLE_USER instead of ROLE_Admin

Answer (score 0):

Your login.jsp form tag points at j_spring_security_check, which isn't an action name in your struts.xml.  Change that to whatever action name which will handle the login post.

If you have written a method in action.LogAction (or implemented execute()) to actually handle your login, you need to provide both a success and a failure result in the struts.xml The success result should take the user to wherever they should be after successful login, the failure result takes them back to the login jsp. See the struts docs [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/coding-struts-2-actions.html) for more info.